# How create a condition NOT greater using .loc in python

Tags: python, pandas

How exclude rows from the data by condition.

- 1- using .loc I selected the part to be removed
- 2- problem is there are empty rows in "year", I want to keep all the empty and anything < 2020

I would use !< but doesn't work, python just accepts !=

```
# dataframe

cw=

year  name
2022   as
2020   ad
       sd
       sd
1988   wwe
1999   we


cw = cw.loc[cw['year']!>'2020']
```

#### The Problem is the empty fields, its tricky... I need keep everything that is NOT > 2020, so I want to keep the empty and smaller values

Comment: "Not greater than" is "less than or equal to"...

Comment: Or you can negate the whole thing with `~(my_exclusion_condition)`. Also why is `2020` in quotes?

Comment: I'm not sure why peter is being downvoted. The question is absolutely a valid one and was asked with a proper example. @pault perhaps the type of year is string in his DF?

Comment: @roganjosh problem is the empty fields, its tricky. I need keep everything that is NOT > 2020, so I want to keep the empty and smaller values

Comment: @Peter one problem you will have is that you currently have your year values as strings. you need to convert to either a timestamp or numeric type so that the `>` operator works correctly.

Comment: @pault I think that is the right way to go, would you help me with syntax ```cw =cw[~cw.loc[cw['year']>'2020']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `not greater than n` the same as `less than or equal to n`?

```
cw = cw.loc[cw['year']!>'2020']
```

simply becomes

```
cw = cw.loc[cw['year'] <= '2020']
```

negating the query will also work but it's important that your "year" column be either an int or a timestamp if you want to make sure the `>` operator works correctly.

Try something more like this:

```
import pandas as pd

cw = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2022, 2020, None, None, 1988, 1999],
                   "name": ["as", "ad", "sd", "sd", "wwe", "we"]}, dtype=int)

"""
   year name
0  2022   as
1  2020   ad
2  None   sd
3  None   sd
4  1988  wwe
5  1999   we
"""

cw = cw.loc[~(cw["year"] > 2020)]
"""
   year name
1  2020   ad
2  None   sd
3  None   sd
4  1988  wwe
5  1999   we
"""
```

Comment: problem is the empty fields, its tricky. I need keep everything that is NOT > 2020, so I want to keep the empty and smaller values

Comment: Ah, in that case negating the query is actually the correct answer.